# Check engine light went out by itself but codes still there. Will these go away and can I pass NYS Ins

Tags: cel, inspection

I had codes for p0352,53,54 and replaced coil, check engine light went out by itself but codes still there. Will these go away and can I pass NYS Inspection with codes still there?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't affect your inspection results at all. The reason is, when they do the emissions on an OBDII vehicle, they are only checking for the readiness indicators and that the system has passed them. The vehicle passes them through what is called a *drive cycle*. If the system has failed one of the drive cycle elements (readiness indicators), the check engine light (CEL) would be on.

The only way it might not pass the test without the CEL on is if the drive cycle itself is not complete. There are (if I remember correctly) eight different elements of the drive cycle. If the drive cycle isn't complete, it doesn't mean you've failed emissions testing, it means the vehicle is not ready for emissions testing. If the ECU has completed the drive cycle and there's no active codes present, the vehicle will pass emissions.

If you disconnected the battery to replace the coils, your car may not be ready. It would need to go through the drive cycle in order to get there. This may or not be completed depending on how far it has been driven since the disconnect, how much gas is in the tank, and several other factors. An easy thing to do would be to take it to a auto parts store and have them check the drive cycle elements. If you do, ensure they DO NOT reset the ECU through their tester, because this will cause you to need to redo the drive cycle. If the battery was disconnected when changing out the coils, the codes would be erased in the process.

For your edification, an "element" (my terminology ... don't know if that's what they are actually called) is something like a test for the O2 sensors or EVAP system.